# Trigger NTP restart after `vagrant resume`

Tags: debian, ntp, vagrant, ntpd, suspend

I manage some Debian 11 server VMs using Vagrant. Sometimes I need to `vagrant suspend` them, and I noticed that after `vagrant resume`, their system time is off. Running `systemctl status ntp` shows the NTP service is turned off by a failure. I could solve this by restarting NTP manually after `vagrant resume`, so I wanted to add a trigger to the Vagrantfile:

```
config.trigger.after :resume do |trigger|
  trigger.info = "Restart NTP"
  trigger.run = {inline: "bash -c 'systemctl start ntp'"}
end
```

...but now `vagrant resume` throws an error:

```
==> xxx-vm: Running action triggers after resume ...
==> xxx-vm: Running trigger...
==> xxx-vm: Restart NTP
    xxx-vm: Running local: Inline script
    xxx-vm: bash -c 'systemctl start ntp'
    xxx-vm: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
    xxx-vm: Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
==> xxx-vm: Trigger run failed
```

I thought this trigger should run after resuming the VM, but apparently the VM is still down when it runs. Is it possible to run a script automatically when a VM is resumed and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: `run` runs a script on the host, to run it on the guest (the VM), `run_remote` has to be used:

```
config.trigger.after :resume do |trigger|
  trigger.info = "Restart NTP"
  trigger.run_remote = {inline: "bash -c 'systemctl start ntp'"}
end
```